# How to update a set of rows based on their (different) primary keys in SQLite (Android)?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a database table that consists of several columns, including `id` (the primary key) and `last_sync` (a timestamp). A background process synchronizes the rows of the table occasionally with a server.

If the process is successful, it returns ...

- one single timestamp, which represents the time of the synchronization
- a list of `id`s. This means that the rows which belong to these ids were successfully synchronized

What I want to do now is to update the `last_sync` column of every row whose `id` is in the list with the new timestamp.

---

Example:

- returned timestamp: 143394245
- returned list: [11,25,64,126]

After the update, the `last_sync` column of rows 11, 25, 64 and 126 should equal 143394245.

---

How could I do this the most efficient way? The list could contain several thousand ids.

The easiest (but most expensive) way would be to iterate over the list and execute an update-statement for every id (`update ... set last_sync = ... where id = ...`) which would result in 1000 updates if the list has 1000 entries. This is of course not what I want to do, especially not on a mobile device.

Another idea would be to do something like `update ... set last_sync = ... where id IN (...)`. The set next to `IN` would contain all of the ids. But how to create that set dynamically.. with a StringBuilder? I think that's very hacky..

I hope there are other ways. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: With a string builder.  Since SQL is always a string, at some point you have to have a string builder.  The ASCII nature of SQL pretty much forces it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your responses, but after some research, I decided to use bulk updates. I found out that bulk updates with only two columns are much faster than expected. A Nexus 5 does over 2000 updates in one second which suits my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Insert or Replace:

```
Insert or Replace into <YourTable> 
last_sync, YT.<othercolumn>, YT.<othercolumn2>
from <YourTable> YT inner join <AnotherTable> ON
YT._id = AT._id
```

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html